# Transfer files using ad-hoc connection in Windows

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, home-networking, ad-hoc-network

How do I configure direct network between computers in home network *beside* Internet connection?

I would like Windows computers to be connected directly omitting router which provides Internet connection. The router is powerful - D-Link DIR-320 with [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/). It is however too slow for home NAS server and sometimes big chunk of data is needed to be send between computers - there is no need to push the data via router.

Those are two computers - Windows 7 and Windows 8. Setting `netsh wlan set hostednetwork` in Windows 8 is really nice but I don't know how to connect from Windows 7 with that *hostednetwork* without loosing Internet connection.

Internet sharing is not an option since each computer can connect to the Internet separately. Also I would like to skip solutions with temporary network switching - both users should be able to use Internet in that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically asking how can I connect to my Filesharing network (from the windows 8 machine) AND be connected to the regular internet at the same time.

SO, basically, with the one built in adapter, you cant. You can either connect to one network or the other. The internet sharing option that you ruled out would have meant only having to add one wireless adapter, but as the question stands a laptop with just one adapter can only connect to one network at a time.

Note: If one is connected wirelessly and one is wired, then a router of some sort or switch with an AP combo would be nescessary.

### If you add a second adapter

Then it gets weird to join to networks the regular way. So i recommend joining through the network adapters page. Right click on the built in adapter- Connect To - (Main Wifi) and Right click on the built in adapter- Connect To - (FileSharingWifi)

### Wired

One final option is to connect the two computers by cable, usually crossover, and set your IPs so that they have the same subnet mask and the last octet (.xx) is different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

By adding files to your public folder which can be accessed by another computer connected to the ad-hoc network. Or sharing user files to the network.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I configure direct network between computers in home network.

Connect them both to the same switch or AP and give them both an IP in the same subnet. Usually this is the default on SoHo devices like your Dlink, so unless you manually set static IPs in different subnets and give two IP ranger to the intenret network on the Dlink this should already work.

Next select one of the computers and enable a shared folder. Make sure it is either writable for everyone (not recommended security wise), or add a username and password. Then connect to it from the other computer using the `\\othercomputername\share` syntax.